# Using multiple SSL certificates with Stunnel

Tags: ssl, stunnel

I have a HAProxy + stunnel setup, I would like to have different certificates for my domain and submdomain.
Certificate 1 - example.com
Certificate 2 - foo.example.com
How do I configure Stunnel to do this? It works fine with just one certificate but I have trouble setting it up for multiple certificates. 
Thanks!

Comment: You run multiple instances of stunnel.  AFAIK it doesn't do multiple certs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With one IP address, you need to use the TLS [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) extension. There's an example config here: https://serverfault.com/a/440563/216353

Server-side SNI requires [stunnel version 4.38](https://www.stunnel.org/sdf_ChangeLog.html) or newer [compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.0](http://www.stunnel.org/static/stunnel.html) or newer.

Also, [client support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Browsers_with_support_for_TLS_server_name_indication.5B6.5D):

- IE7+
- Chrome 6+
- Firefox 2+
- Opera 8+
- Safari 3+
- iOS4+

Also note that Windows XP does not support the SNI extension.

Comment: bennettp123, welcome to SF.  That's a cracking, textbook first answer - +1 from me.